# What is the difference between this.varable and this.state.variable in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between

```
class App extends Component {
   open = false

   render () {
     <Button onPress=(() => { this.open = false}) />
   }
}

class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
     this.state({
        open: false
     })
   }

   render () {
     <Button onPress=(() => { this.setState({ open: true })}) />
   }
}
```

For me, it works the same, and I used `this` without a state and never had issues.

Answer (score 2):

`this.open` is referring to the property of class `App` while  `this.state`, if you are using React, it is referring to your components local state.

`this.setState({ open: true })` will update the state and also rerenders your components while `this.open = false` will not trigger any rerenders

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not using `open` inside your `render` method. Changing state re-renders the component with different data, while class properties doesn't.

To better understand the difference, you could try clicking the button in these two classes:

```
class App extends Component {
   open = false

   render () {
     let isOpen = "Not open"
     if (this.open) {
         isOpen = "Open!"
     }
     return (<View><Button onPress=(() => { this.open = false}) /><Text>{isOpen}</Text></View>)
   }
}

class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
     this.state({
        open: false
     })
   }

   render () {
     let isOpen = "Not open"
     if (this.state.open) {
         isOpen = "Open!"
     }
     return (<View><Button onPress=(() => { this.setState({ open: true })}) /><Text>{isOpen}</Text></View>)
   }
}
```